# What causes error: Spatial reference of input image and samples don't match

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, otb-applications

I checked that the CRS is the same. I want to train the classifier in OTB to recognize "non-vegetation" and "vegetation" on an orthomosaic. I created a polygon layer with the two classes, and did 30 sample polygons of each. However I keep getting the error "Spatial reference of input image and samples don't match ". I am using QGIS 3.16.0 and the OTB 7.2.0 plug-in.

Does anyone know what might cause this error?

Comment: I faced the same issue several time even if "apparently" both are in the same projection. What I do in that case is using "Warp (reproject)" tool on the raster and "Reproject layer" tool on the vector to force-reproject both to the same CRS and it works.

Comment: Thank you very much. That seems to solve it.